# Перенос span на другую строку

Tags: html, css

Есть такой код:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Account" asp-anti-forgery="true">
            <div class="validation" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>

            <div class="input-group">

                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">E-mail</span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Email" />

                <span asp-validation-for="Email" />


            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span id="basic-addon1" class="input-group-text">Пароль</span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="Password" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Войти" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row ml-auto"><img style="width:35rem;" src="~/images/soldier.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Получается сначала все нормально:

[image: До валидации]

Но если вдруг срабатывает validation.js, то получается это:

[image: После валидации]

Хочу перенести предупреждение вниз, но не понимаю, какие свойства использовать. 
Пробовал следующее:

`display:block, flex, inline-block
white-space:normal`

Но не помогает

Comment: Пробовали после input прописать тэг `<br>`?

Comment: Тоже не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, span можно задать как display: block и не оборачивать дивом.
Плюс я так понимаю это bootstrap4, использую редко но возможно input-group это флекс контейнер и потому для span нужно прописать:

```css
input-group {
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал поместить span после , что так же, как и все остальное не помогло, но если его поместить в еще один div, то все работает.

```
    <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">E-mail</span>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Email" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" />
                </div>
```

Поторопился с вопросом, все-таки был близок  к ответу, прошу прощения.
Если есть альтернативные решения, которые еще лучше, я буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">E-mail</span>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Email" />
</div>
<div asp-validation-for="Email"></div>
```